# modify the function using functional programming

Tags: kotlin

Please help me, I started learning kotlin and got to functional programming. I need this set to have exactly 9 elements. Please tell me.

```
val uniquePatrons : Set<String> = generateSequence {
    val first = patronList.randomizer()
    val last = lastName.randomizer()
    "$first $last"
}.take(10).toSet()
```

Comment: `generateSequence { ... }.distinct().take(9).toSet()`

Comment: If your randomiser values are guaranteed to be unique, you could also just do _List(9) { ... }.toSet()_. _generateSequence_ is necessary when you want to generate elements lazily, which is not the case in your code.